# How To set domain for cookie golang with "contrib/sessions" package, gin gonic

Tags: session, cookies, go, go-gin

Please help me!. I wanna set domain for my cookie,
In my main function, i set :

```
store := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secretkey"))
store.Options(sessions.Options{
    Domain: "myexample.com",
})
router.Use(sessions.Sessions("mysession", store))
```

In my first handler function, i set:

```
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    session.Set("test", "test value")
    session.Save()
```

In another handler, i get the "test" session by:

```
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    result = session.Get("test")
```

But the problem is the value of result is nil, if i remove

```
    store.Options(sessions.Options{
    Domain: "myexample.com",
})
```

in main function, it will work. So anyone can explain for me. 
Moreover, if i get session "test" in my first handler function, it will be ok.

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you using your web browser or some automated test? Which URL are you using to test it?

Comment: i use web browser, And the url i test is "myexample.com". Thanks for reply

Comment: Can you post the first handler code?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/yUQzMEOC84 @PabloLalloni